# Undesired horizontal scroll on display-inline container

Tags: css

I have a container with two children that I would like to display inline. Think it like a container element that has an agreement text on it.

Here is the codepen that shows the current code:
https://codepen.io/alansouzati/pen/yXPrvQ

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to properly display the label side-by-side with the checkbox in a way that it would not overflow. These texts tend to be long and this is where the problem shows.

Currently I'm seeing a horizontal scroll inside the box that I have no idea where it is coming from.

Any ideas what I'm missing in the code?

```
.container {
  width: 288px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 6px 24px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.checkbox,
.label {
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.label {
  word-break: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: calc(100% - 24px)
}
```

Comment: Removing `overflow: scroll` fixes your issue.

Comment: I put it there intentionally to see why there overflow is there.

Comment: basically I don't understand where the overflow is coming from

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Your codepen shows the text in line with the checkbox and the text does not flow outside the borders.  What is the issue then?

Comment: The issue is that this container in my app is a generic one, I cannot remove the overflow from there. So, I wanted to understand why the browser is adding a scroll in this example. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow under `scroll` section: "Browsers display scrollbars whether or not any content is actually clipped."

Comment: I've updated the pen and the question to use overflow: auto. again, this is just to show there is an overflow coming from some place.

Comment: Subtract more pixels? `width: calc(100% - 28px)` seems to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I know at some point the scrolling stops. 28px seems to be the number, but I don't understand where this 4px gap is coming from.

Comment: I found it. there is a margin of 2 px that the browser applies to the checkbox.

Comment: I removed my comment to post that, but you beat me to it. Nice. It's actually 3px 3px 3px 4px, which would make sense why 28px works for the calculation.

Comment: can you post this as an answer? I will approve it :)

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem had nothing to do with the margin in the native checkbox but with an actual spacing character in the DOM.

Check this codepen: https://codepen.io/alansouzati/pen/YQEmdN

Instead of:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </span>
  <span class="label">this is a really long label that I would like to wrap</span>
</div>
```

I did

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </span><span class="label">this is a really long label that I would like to wrap</span>
</div>
```

And the scroll is now gone.

This is probably some issue with the way codepen is rendering the code, but in my actual application I don't have to bother about it. But in my case it is hard to validate because I'm using JSX + React.

Comment: Closed this a a dupe, which explains exactly what is going on here and why your _fix_ solved it, and it has nothing to do with Codepen :)

Comment: thanks that really helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You get the scroll because your `.container` has `overflow: auto` and `white-space: nowrap`;

If I had to do it, I would remove those properties and use flexbox to solve it in a cleaner way, without doing explicit calculations for adjusting user agent styles as different browsers will apply different styles to these elements.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I agree we should not rely on the browser's margin. Also agree that flexbox would be more elegant. Although the actual fix has nothing to do with margin in the checkbox element but with whitespace in the actual DOM. I will post another answer.